# How to pass an array of pointers, and to let the function find the size of array?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to pass an array of pointers to a function, without the need to define the size.
Also the output is a warning  "initialization makes pointer from integer without cast.
Mostly interested in passing array of pointers rather than an array because I'm **trying to understand how to deal with the instance when Data is a dynamically allocated memory using malloc**

Why is this happening, and how can I pass an array of pointers as an argument, without the need to define its size?

```
Code:

#include <stdio.h>

void printData(int *data[]);


void main (int argc,char *argv[]){

    int *Data[] = {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42};
    printData(Data);

}

void printData(int *data[]){

    int **cur_data = data;
    int counter = sizeof(data)/sizeof(int);
    for(int i = 0; i<counter; i++){
        printf("%d. %d\n", i, *cur_data);
        cur_data++;
    }
}
```

---

```
Warning:

main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:9: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
main.c:9: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
main.c:9: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
main.c:9: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
main.c:9: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
main.c:9: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
gcc   main.o -o run
```

---

```
Run: 
0. 4
```

Comment: `int *Data[] = {4, ..., 42};` You are declaring an array of pointers to `int`, and filling it with `int`s... This doesn't have much chances to work.

Comment: Why do you want to calculate the length automatically. Why not send it as another argument or as first member of array?

Comment: Always pass at least one pointer[0] that points to the size?

Comment: Define a struct that has the size as a member and pass that instead?

Comment: @MohitJain I was curious to see if it's possible

Comment: Use pointer arithmetic to store the size below the first pointer?

Comment: Aren't these the same numbers from Lost?

Comment: look at how `int main(int argc, char **argv) {}` does it: there are two ways: 1) a count as an extra argument 2) a sentinel value *in* the array. main() uses both methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, an array decays into a pointer when is passed to a function, pass `counter` as a parameter to `printData`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printData(int *data, int counter);

int main(void)
{
    int Data[] = {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42};
    int counter = sizeof(Data) / sizeof(int);

    printData(Data, counter);
    return 0;
}

void printData(int *data, int counter)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        printf("%d. %d\n", i, data[i]);
    }
}
```

Or you can store the counter into the first element of array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printData(int *data);

int main(void)
{
    int Data[] = {0, 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42};

    Data[0] = sizeof(Data) / sizeof(int) - 1;
    printData(Data + 1);
    return 0;
}

void printData(int *data)
{
    int counter = data[-1];

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        printf("%d. %d\n", i, data[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about if you try to allocate memory dynamically for Data using malloc, then pass that as an argument?

Comment: @echad, makes no difference

Comment: @echad: you will need to keep track of the number of elements you allocated, and pass that with the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the corrected program, when you pass an array to a function, it becomes a pointer and loses its size information, so needs to pass separately

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printData(int *data, int size);


int main (int argc,char *argv[]){

    int Data[] = {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42};
    printData(Data, sizeof(Data));
    return 0;
}

void printData(int *data, int size){
    int *cur_data = data;
    int counter = size/sizeof(int);
    for(int i = 0; i<counter; i++){
        printf("%d. %d\n", i, *cur_data);
        cur_data++;
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
0. 4
1. 8
2. 15
3. 16
4. 23
5. 42
```

Comment: What about if you try to allocate memory dynamically for Data using malloc, then pass that as an argument?

Comment: even the  sizeof a pointer is just 4 bytes on 32-bit system

Answer (score 1):

You declared array Data as an array of pointers but initialized it with integral constants instead of addresses.

```
int *Data[] = {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42};
```

So the compiler issues diagnostic messages.

You can do the task the following way that is by using a sentinal value that in this case is equal to NULL.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printData( int *data[] );


int main(void) 
{
    int Values[] = { 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( Values ) / sizeof( *Values );
    int *Data[N+1];
    size_t i;

    i = 0;
    for ( ; i < N; i++ )
    {
        Data[i] = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
        *Data[i] = Values[i];
    }
    Data[i] = NULL;

    printData( Data );

    for ( i = 0; i < N + 1; i++ ) free( Data[i] );

    return 0;
}

void printData( int *data[] )
{
    int **p = data;
    size_t i = 0;

    for( ; *p != NULL; ++p, ++i )
    {
        printf("%d. %d\n", i, **p );
    }
}
```

The output is

```
0. 4
1. 8
2. 15
3. 16
4. 23
5. 42
```

Take into account that function main shall have return type `int`

Comment: If you use a variable length array, then you don't need to use `malloc`, anyway there is no need to (m)allocate for each value, a single `malloc` is enought: http://ideone.com/YN90yO

Comment: @Alter Mann  I used separate malloc under the expression that the original code initialize each element of the array.:) So initially I wanted to write something as int *Data = { malloc( sizeof( int ) ), malloc( sizeof( int ), /*...*? }; :)

Answer (score 0):

Where-

```
int *Data[];
```

where `data` is a array of pointer to an integer. This array pointer can point to 1D arrays or integer. But you are filling with integer data. For 1D array use

```
int Data[]={4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42};
```

And there is no way to know the size of the array using pointer! Only way is pass the no of element to the function with address of an array!

Try these changes-

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printData(int *data,int element);


void main (int argc,char *argv[]){

    int Data[] = {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42};
    printData(Data,6);

}

void printData(int *data, int element){

    int *cur_data = data;
    int counter = (sizeof(data)*element)/sizeof(int);
    for(int i = 0; i<counter; i++){
        printf("%d. %d\n", i, *cur_data);
        cur_data++;
    }
}
```

Comment: No 2D array in here. An `int*` doesn't necessarily point to an array.